# Postgre regex replace

Tags: regex, postgresql

I'm trying to clear text fields from html tags with regex.

This query works as expected

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('<span>foobar</span><span><br><br></span>', '<.*?>', ' ', 'g')
```

returning 'foobar', but adding variation for other types of tags

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('<span>foobar</span><span><br><br></span>', '<.*?>|&([a-z0-9]+|#[0-9]{1,6}|#x[0-9a-f]{1,6})', ' ', 'g')
```

returns a blank line.

Any idea why, looks like I'm using | operator wrong, but I don't understand what the errror is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing greedy and non-greedy quantifiers in the same pattern within the alternatives on the same nesting level, it often leads to ambiguous behavior with PostreSQL regex.

Use greedy quantifiers, the `<.*?>` can be safely replaced with `<[^>]*>` or `<[^<>]*>`:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(
    '<span>foobar</span><span><br><br></span>', 
    '<[^<>]*>|&([a-z0-9]+|#[0-9]{1,6}|#x[0-9a-f]{1,6})', ' ', 'g')
      ^^^^^^
```

See the [PostgreSQL demo](https://rextester.com/JJZTB66595), resulting in

[image]